# Import Error : Calling python script from shell

Tags: python, shell, python-import, importerror, pythonpath

I want to run my python script from a shell.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import time

from path.to.my.function1 import function1
from path.to.my.function2 import function2

  #some code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

From my shell command, I want to run it like this:

```
./myPythonScript.py
```

The result is :

```
ImportError: No module named path.to.my.function1
```

When I run it from Eclipse for example, I don't have any errors. I have some empty _ *init* _.py files in my directories.

I don't want to add

```
sys.path.append(0, /path/to/my/function1)
```

because it needs to be easily exportable. Also I don't want to add my file path to the source folder of PYTHONPATH. It needs to be plug and play.

I don't know if i have a different compiler or I should modify my #! /usr/bin/python. Or could it be my PYTHONPATH ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code a python package and then you will be able to do so. 
Simply add `__init__.py` script to the directory and add a `__main__.py` script to your directory. In the `__main__.py`
 add the code you do after `if __name__ == '__main__'`. 
For import add the following line:
    `from .path.to.my.script import foo`

Finally, run python -m < directory name >. Outside your package directory.

Comment: Should I still put #! usr/bin/python ?  I will take a look at packages!

Comment: Not necessary. You are declaring using python when you command: python -m < package >

Comment: I still have the same error if I used a _main_.py (the packages). Thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit your question to have your full state (code, files and command line), so I can help you :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your time :) . it is now working since i have put all my files(.py) in the same folder(directory). Unfortunately, I want the .py files be in different folders.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't do so. There are 4 options to import scripts which are not installed/base modules of python: 1. relative import (inside a package) 2. .pth file in the python site-packages directory. 3. symlink to your script in python site-packages directory 4. sys.path.append as you mentioned.

Comment: I have to correct myself. What I was trying to say is that I only now used __relative imports__. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package/root where the package root is the directory above `path`

Comment: no the thing is that I don't want to use the whole path. If we change the location of the repo (for example), I don't want to go and chnage all the path in every files

Comment: All you have to do, then, is use `PYTHONPATH=relative/path/to/your/package/root`. For example, `PYTHONPATH=.` will set the PYTHONPATH to the current directory you're in.

Answer (score 0):

use -m to run your code, like python -m myPythonScript, import modules as scripts. it works for me.